# Creating a single hexagon in C# using DrawPolygon

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Ok so i have created a triangle but I cant for the life of me work out the coordinates to create a simple hexagon,

```
Point[] shape = new Point[3];        
            shape[0] = new Point(200, 100);        
            shape[1] = new Point(300, 200);
            shape[2] = new Point(100, 200);
```

This makes a triangle but I cant figure out the x and y values for a hexagon, sounds like a simple question but my brain just isn't working correctly today, Below is the array for the hexagon I just can't figure out the values.

```
Point[] shape = new Point[6];        
                shape[0] = new Point(0, 0);         
                shape[1] = new Point(0, 0);
                shape[2] = new Point(0, 0);     
                shape[3] = new Point(0, 0);
                shape[4] = new Point(0, 0);
                shape[5] = new Point(0, 0);
```

Any help would be great thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since I've already written a comment, I guess I should demonstrate that in some real code.

I created a WinForms application with a `Panel` object on which I can draw. Then I've overridden the `Paint` event on that to draw me a hexagon.

```
    private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        var graphics = e.Graphics;

        //Get the middle of the panel
        var x_0 = panel1.Width / 2;
        var y_0 = panel1.Height / 2;

        var shape = new PointF[6];

        var r = 70; //70 px radius 

        //Create 6 points
        for(int a=0; a < 6; a++)
        {
            shape[a] = new PointF(
                x_0 + r * (float)Math.Cos(a * 60 * Math.PI / 180f), 
                y_0 + r * (float)Math.Sin(a * 60 * Math.PI / 180f));
        }

        graphics.DrawPolygon(Pens.Red, shape);            
    }
```

This then draws

[image: hexagon]

As I said, the key is to view the hexagon as a "discrete" circle. The points are all computed as being on the outer part of a perfect circle, which are then connected with a straight line. You can create all regular `n-Point` shapes with this technique (a pentagon e.g. as a `5-regular` shape ;))

So, you just "inscribe" the 6 points in the circle to get your hexagon, as shown in this diagram with a regular 5-point shape:

[image: hexa2]

Then remember that you can compute the `(x,y)` coordinates of a point given its polar coordinates `(r, phi)` as

[image: coordinate_trafo]

[image]

To which you can also add an offset [image: offset], which is in my case the center of the frame I'm drawing in.

Comment: Hey great answer, can you help me rotate this to look something [like this](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/a6/bb/2c/a6bb2c08aac377e19808b861a252b722.jpg) ? When getting the centroid , it returns 0,0

Comment: @soulshined You need to offset the phase / angle by an offset `alpha_0`. Replace `a` by `30 + a` or so in the above code (in `sin()` and `cos()` calls) and see what happens. That will shift the angle of the first (and following) points by an initial angle, giving you that rotation.

Comment: you sir are fantastic - 11° was the magical number. I still don't get why the centroid is `{0,0}` but that's for another question I suppose. Thank you for your help, I really appreciate it!

Comment: @soulshined I didn't quite get what you meant by 'centroid'. The center of the object? The first point? The hexagon is intentionally centered around the middle of the panel (the middle coordinates are computed in `x_0` and `y_0` and are taken as the center of the coordinate system, in a sense). The first point should also not be at `(0,0)` with respect to the center.